# Utilizing CanonicalName oposed to distinguished name

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, powershell-4.0

I would like to use canonicalname instead of distinguished name for the reason of sort in a csv is much more cleaner.
I know I have to put the properties value in, but the question is where. I don't know if it goes in the $oulist or the $users variable. Here is my code.

```
Import-Module activeDirectory
$output = Read-Host "'Y' for output to file or any key for output in GUI table view" -foreground Cyan
$fqdn = Read-Host "Enter FQDN domain"
$cred = Get-Credential

Write-Host "Contacting $fqdn domain..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$domain = (get-addomain $fqdn -Credential $cred | select distinguishedName, pdcEmulator, DNSroot, DomainControllersContainer)

Write-Host "Completed. Enumerating OUs.." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$OUlist = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $domain.distinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree -Server $domain.DNSroot)
Write-Host "Completed. Counting users..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$newlist = foreach ($OU in $OUlist)
{
#The array will automatically have a count property, no need for measure
$Users = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -Server $domain.pdcEmulator
#Again you already have all of the user object before the loop, just            write-progress for the OUlist that you are looping through
write-progress -Activity "Counting users" -Status "Finding users in $OU" -PercentComplete ([array]::indexof($OUlist, $OU)/$OUlist.count * 100)
[pscustomobject]@{
    OU = $OU.DistinguishedName; Count = ($Users.Count)

    }
}
if ($output -eq "Y")
{
    $newlist | Export-CSV .\OUuserCount.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
    Write-Host "All done!" -ForegroundColor yellow
}
else
{
$newList | Out-GridView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  All I needed to do is change two values.
I added the properties value of canonicalname

```
$OUlist = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Credential $cred -properties CanonicalName -SearchBase $domain.distinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree    -Server $domain.DNSroot)
```

and I changed the Array value of OU

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    OU = $OU.CanonicalName; Count = ($Users.Count)

}
```